# Help me with this SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

3 tables are defined as follows:

**Users**

```
User_ID      INT
First_Name   VARCHAR
Last_Name    VARCHAR
Email        VARCHAR
```

**Roles**

```
Role_ID      INT
Role_Name    VARCHAR
Access_Level INT
```

**Roles_Users**

```
User_ID      INT
Role_ID      INT
```

`Roles_Users` is a many-to-many linking table between `Users` and `Roles`. I want to pull back the following info:

```
First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Role_Name
```

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
    U.First_Name,
    U.Last_Name,
    U.Email,
    R.Name AS Role_Name
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN Roles_Users RU ON U.User_ID = RU.User_ID
INNER JOIN Roles R ON RU.Role_ID = R.Role_ID
```

The tricky part (at least for me) is that I want to only pull back the `Role_Name` with the `MIN(Access_Level)` for that particular user. So basically the record set I want to pull will have each user only listed once with their lowest access level role name.

I'm sure this is pretty simple but it's just stumping me right now.

Thanks

Comment: That's why I hate *many-to-many* tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) in conjunction with the `ROW_NUMBER` windowing function like this:

```
;WITH MinAccessData AS
(
SELECT 
    U.First_Name,
    U.Last_Name,
    U.Email,
    R.Name AS Role_Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY U.User_ID ORDER BY R.Access_Level) AS RowNum
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN Roles_Users RU ON U.User_ID = RU.User_ID
INNER JOIN Roles R ON RU.Role_ID = R.Role_ID
)
SELECT *
FROM MinAccessData
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

The CTE "partitions" your data by `User_ID`, e.g. each user gets a "partition". Inside that partition, the roles are ordered by `Access_level` and the smallest is the first one - so it gets `RowNum = 1` - for each user.

So you then select from that CTE all those entries where the `RowNum = 1` - this delivers all the entries for each user which have the smallest `Access_Level` value.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives without a CTE (just to have another tool in your box)

```
SELECT 
    U.First_Name,
    U.Last_Name,
    U.Email,
    R.Name AS Role_Name
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN Roles_Users RU ON U.User_ID = RU.User_ID
INNER JOIN Roles R ON RU.Role_ID = R.Role_ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT
                MIN(r.Access_Level) access_level,
                ru.UserID,
            FROM Roles r
                INNER JOIN Roles_Users ru
                ON r.Role_ID  = ru.Role_ID
            GROUP BY UserID
                ) minAccess 
ON ru.UserId = minAccess.UserId
   and ru. 
  ON r.access_level = minAccess .access_level
```

You can also use a CROSS APPLY

```
 SELECT 
        U.First_Name,
        U.Last_Name,
        U.Email,
        R.Name AS Role_Name
    FROM Users U
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                    Role_Name
                  FROM  Roles_Users RU ON U.User_ID = RU.User_ID
                      INNER JOIN Roles R ON RU.Role_ID = R.Role_ID
                  WHERE u.user_id = ru.user_id
                  ORDER BY 
                         Access_Level desc
                    )
```

Comment: Works - but only for "top 1" - try doing "Top 3" or "Top 5" with this ..... that's why I **love** the CTE's!

Comment: @Aaron. Nothing except that marc_s was faster  Oh and its nice to know the portable solutions

Comment: Ok, I wasn't looking at edit history, your opening comment made it sound desirable to avoid a CTE, that's all. :-)

Comment: @Marc_s the CROSS APPLY can do TOP N without a CTE. Not that I'm against CTE's. (In fact I'm currently writing on an Oracle query that's got about 5 of them)

Answer (score 1):

Correlated subquery:

```
SELECT 
    U.First_Name,
    U.Last_Name,
    U.Email,
(
select top 1 R.RName from Roles_Users RU ON U.User_ID = RU.User_ID
INNER JOIN Roles R ON RU.Role_ID = R.Role_ID
ORDER BY R.Access_Level
)
AS Role_Name
FROM Users U
```

In my opinion using a subquery is easier to read and write. In this code the correlated subquery will execute 1x per row returned. I like @Conrad's inner join solution, easiest and probably the most performant, and probably what i would use, just giving this as another option.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but it goes something like this

```
SELECT 
    U.First_Name,
    U.Last_Name,
    U.Email,
    R.Role_Name
FROM Users U
JOIN Roles_Users RU ON U.User_ID = RU.User_ID
JOIN (
       SELECT ROLE_ID, MIN(ROLE_NAME) ROLE_NAME
       FROM ROLES
       GROUP BY ROLE_ID
       HAVING ACCESS_LEVEL = MIN(ACCESS_LEVEL)
     ) R ON RU.Role_ID = R.Role_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Users.*, Roles.*
FROM
    Users
    JOIN Roles_Users ON Users.User_ID = Roles_Users.User_ID
    JOIN Roles ON Roles.Role_ID = Roles_Users.Role_ID
WHERE
    Access_Level = (
        SELECT MIN(Access_Level)
        FROM
            Roles_Users
            JOIN Roles ON Roles.Role_ID = Roles_Users.Role_ID
        WHERE Users.User_ID = Roles_Users.User_ID
    )
```

NOTE: This will not list users without any role.